# rails 3 returning to site user logged out

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, spree

I've integrated dotPay to my Spree site for payments. The user after choosing this option is redirected from my site to dotPay's. He pays what is needed there and then he can click a button which will return him to my site. And here lays the problem. When he returns he is no longer logged in and I need him to be.

A bit strange thing (to me maybe) he is being redirected via POST request - can't change that. With that I also get a warning `Can't verify CSRF token authenticity` not sure if that might have anything to do with it.

Any suggestion are very much welcome.

P.S. I'm using Spree 1-3-stable, Rails 3.2.13, Devise 2.2.3, Ruby 1.9.3

Comment: Verify that you're sending `authenticity_token` in params. If not, Rails thinks you're doing a CSRF attack, that's the reason of a redirect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, in the end I've ended up with removing the CSRF verification. I'm not 100% sure, but I can't send my `authenticity_token` to dotPay (well, I can, but they won't return it). However, they are generating a md5, which I can check and also I'm checking the IP address where it's coming from.

Comment: You can make an exception solely for the controller action which is triggered by the user completing payment and returning to your site. No sense in disabling it site-wide.

Answer (score 1):

For specific actions, you can disable CSRF checking by adding a line like this to the controller:

```
protect_from_forgery :except => [:callback_from_dotpay]
```

conversely, you can specify which actions *to* protect, like this:

```
protect_from_forgery :only => [:create, :update, :delete]
```

Alternatively, to turn it off completely for an entire controller, you can do this (Rails 2, 3):

```
skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token
```

If you decide to jump on the bleeding edge, Rails 4 wants you to do it this way:

```
skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token
```